# Actor for vtkSplineRepresentation ()

Tags: python, actor, vtk

I have two *vtkSplineRepresentation ()* and two viewports. I want to bound a view with a Spline. I know that in order to do this I have to create an Actor. But the problem is that I do not know how. I tried the VtkActor command but I only show a ball, not a set of points, I also tried LineActor but I got an error. Can anybody help me?

The function is as follow:

```
def Spline(self,crv,ren,iren):

    extract = vtk.vtkExtractVOI()
    puntosVTK=dental_curve.puntos_vtk(crv)

    spline = vtk.vtkSplineWidget() 
    spline.InitializeHandles(puntosVTK) #insertamos los puntos       
    spline.SetCurrentRenderer(ren)
    spline.SetDefaultRenderer(ren)

    spline.SetInputConnection(extract.GetOutputPort())
    spline.SetInteractor(iren)
    spline.ProjectToPlaneOn()
    spline.SetProjectionNormalToXAxes()
    spline.On()
    return spline
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the polydata from your vtkSplineRepresenatation (through GetPolyData()) and pass it to a vtkPolyDataMapper, then use the vtkPolyDataMapper to your actor. You did not post code so there's nothing I can't fix, but to give you an idea:

```
mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
geometry = vtk.vtkPolyData()
spline.GetPolyData(geometry))
mapper.SetInputData(geometry)
mapper.Update()

actor = vtk.vtkActor()
actor.SetMapper(mapper)
```

Comment: i still having problems, now the error is: GetPolyData()  takes exactly 1 argument (0given) i dont know what argument i must give. my code now is at the begining

Comment: It appears that the GetPolyData call does not return the vtkPolyData, it fills the one given as parameter. I edited the answer, hope it helps...